# How to upload photos to a image hosting server programmatically?

Tags: java, python, image, http

Hi guys I was wondering how does one upload pics to a image hosting site programmatically through python or java (python preferred).
The site gives no ftp access just through a upload button on the site i.e only http access.
Now I don't want any code here..I just cant figure out how to start out if u can guide me in the right direction it will be helpful.

```
    <form method="post" name="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="theValue">
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="file" name="imagefile[]" size="27"><br><br>  
    <input type="file" name="imagefile[]" size="27"><br><br> 
    <input type="file" name="imagefile[]" size="27"><br><br> 
    <input type="file" name="imagefile[]" size="27"><br><br> 
    <input type="file" name="imagefile[]" size="27"><br><br>  
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152">
</div>
<p><a href="javascript:;" onclick="addElement();">Upload more</a></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
<p></p>
</form>
```

the web form.

Comment: Do you want to upload to some specific hosting? If not then you should look for image hosting that provides and api, e.g. http://imgur.com/ and their api http://api.imgur.com/ Also there are a lot of examples of how to work with imgur, e.g. http://www.mutaku.com/wp/index.php/2011/05/uploading-images-to-imgur-with-python/

Comment: you say they have a upload button, so i guess there is some kind of a webform. you have to create a post or get-request and send it to the site the web-form  is sending it (take a look at the sourecode of the page).

Comment: @vader: I dont think they have a api.

Comment: @peko: yes they have a web form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *******************************

### ATTENTION: This answer is outdated since the time it was written. Use requests library.

**http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/**

### *******************************

---

---

This is a code sample that "just works" for me. It uses MultipartPostHandler for uploading files.

```
import urllib2
import MultipartPostHandler

params = {'file':open( "FILENAME.JPG" , 'rb')}
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
req = urllib2.Request( "PROCESS.PHP" , params)
text_response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().strip()
```

MultipartPostHandler is available at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MultipartPostHandler/0.1.0

Comment: You sure it works? Its the first time I had an answer accepted :-)