# Python curl usage inconsistency

Tags: python, solr, python-2.x

I have a python script that is using curl to post a file into a SOLR collection.

The command looks like this,

```
solrURL = "http://mySolr:8983/solr/solrdatabase/update/csv?commit=true --data-binary @+"fileName" -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'"
print "=====SOLR URL====="
print solrURL
print "=====SENDING TO SOLR====="
subprocess.call(['curl', '-v', solrURL])
```

However, when it does this, it does this,

> GET http://mySolr:8983/solr/solrdatabase/update/csv?commit=true --data-binary @+"fileName" -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8' HTTP/1.1

When it should be using a POST. If I do the command manually in terminal, it works fine. Any ideas why it does this when I try to use a python script?

Comment: i'm suprised the python documentation isn't more explicit about passing command options:( http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: Do use Python's urllib2 (with Multipartposthandler) to upload stuff to Solr. If you wanted CURL functionality (which is overkill in this case), you should be using libCURL rather than CURL from commandline. See my answer on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414419/how-to-upload-photos-to-a-image-hosting-server-programmatically/7416193#7416193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing a list into `subprocess.call`, you should separate the args into individual elements in the string:

```
solrURL = "http://mySolr:8983/solr/solrdatabase/update/csv?commit=true"
subprocess.call(['curl', '-v', solrURL,  '--data-binary', '@+"fileName"', '-H', 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'])
```

What you're seeing is that all your arguments are being interpreted as one argument and cUrl's using that long string with spaces as the URL.

Comment: Realized this after staring at the code for awhile. Thanks for the response though :)